# i am facing this error when creating database through script. mysql

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-error-1064

```
create table arpa_acc_perfil
(
   id_account           integer not null,
   dt_create            date,
   ind_active           tinyint,
   tp_servicio          set('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20'),
   tp_propiedad         set('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20'),
   set_properties       set('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20'),
   ind_piscina          tinyint,
   num_parking          smallint,
   num_wc               smallint,
   num_dormitorios      smallint,
   int_superficie_const smallint,
   int_superficie       smallint,
   precio_alquiler      decimal(10,0),
   precio_compra        decimal(10,0),
   txt_comment          varchar(255),
   primary key (id_account)
)

type = innodb
character set = utf8
MySQL said: Documentation
```

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'type = innodb
>   character set = utf8' at line 20

Comment: Its `Engine=InnoDB` instead of `type = innodb`

Comment: Refer the [InnoDB Table creation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-innodb-tables.html)

Answer (score 2):

You query is incorrect

```
create table arpa_acc_perfil
(
   id_account           integer not null,
   dt_create            date,
   ind_active           tinyint,
   tp_servicio          set('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20'),
   tp_propiedad         set('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20'),
   set_properties       set('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20'),
   ind_piscina          tinyint,
   num_parking          smallint,
   num_wc               smallint,
   num_dormitorios      smallint,
   int_superficie_const smallint,
   int_superficie       smallint,
   precio_alquiler      decimal(10,0),
   precio_compra        decimal(10,0),
   txt_comment          varchar(255),
   primary key (id_account)
)

ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8
```

This is the correct query.